# Validating fields that aren't in the model/controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm a relative newbie at Rails, so forgive me if my question's got an obvious answer.

I'm trying to include a field in a Rails form which isn't in the model/controller or the migration associated with the view.

The form is a simple public contact form, and I can validate against most of the fields easily enough. Eg name, email etc.

The model is form_submission.rb

However, I have a field in the contact form - captcha - which isn't mirrored in the form_submissions db table, etc.

There is a separate table, model etc for captcha which is captcha_answer.rb (etc)

The attributes for captcha_answer in the migration are: answer and is_correct.

The table simple contains a list of answers to a predefined question, some of which are true and some which are false.

Eg, the captcha question might be:

Which is these is an animal?

With the options of: cat, dog, tree, rabbit .. in a select.

What I want to be able to do is to validate that:

a) The captcha field exists in the POST (return message of "no captcha given" if not)
b) The answer given has a value in captcha_answers.is_correct of true (return message of "you gave a wrong answer" if not)

The capcha_answers.answer is always unique, so I want to do the equivalent of a SQL query which gets the first record where captcha_answers.answer =  and returns the value of captcha_answers.is_correct

Like I say, if the attribute was in form_submissions then I'd be able to validate it no problem, but I can't figure out how I can validate a field against something in another model.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you think to use some plugin? https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_captcha or https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha

Comment: Thanks. In this instance I want to do it the "hard" way, as it's partly a learning exercise. For future projects, I may well do that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define accessors for the extra field and use usual ActiveRecord validations:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :extra_field

  validates :extra_field, :presence => true

  validate :custom_validation_method

  def custom_validation_method
    errors.add :extra_field, :invalid unless extra_field == "correct"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It gets me so far, but then when it gets passed to the create, I'm getting an "undefined method" - presumably on .captcha

The basic structure of the create is:

  def create
    '@'form_submission = FormSubmission.new(params[:form_submission])
    # Save the object
    if @form_submission.save
      redirect_to('/thanks.html')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

Any idea how I can stop the controller trying to create a value for the captcha, if that's what it's doing?

Answer (score 2):

You can just add for example a hidden field and catch it in the controller:

in your form:

```
<%= hidden_field(:signup, :pass_confirm, :value => 'abcd') %>
```

then in the controller:

```
params[:signup]
```

There you can access a different model and validate the answer.

Action in the controller like:

```
def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])

    puts "extra field:" 
    puts params[:signup]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
        format.html { redirect_to @company, :notice => 'Company was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @company.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got the field in the form, but the problem is catching it at the the other end and validating. 

Eg it's the "There you can access a different model and validate the answer." bit that I'm struggling with.